# Solving the similar recurrence: T(n) = 3T(n/3) + n/3

Tags: algorithm, big-o, recurrence

Given..

```
T(0) = 3 for n <= 1

T(n) = 3T(n/3) + n/3 for n > 1
```

So the answer's suppose to be `O(nlogn)`.. Here's how I did it and it's not giving me the right answer:

```
T(n) = 3T(n/3) + n/3

T(n/3) = 3T(n/3^2) + n/3^2
```

Subbing this into T(n) gives..

```
T(n) = 3(3T(n/3^2) + n/3^2) + n/3

T(n/3^2) = 3(3(3T(n/3^3) + n/3^3) + n/3^2) + n/3
```

Eventually it'll look like..

```
T(n) = 3^k (T(n/3^k)) + cn/3^k
```

Setting `k = lgn..`

```
T(n) = 3^lgn * (T(n/3^lgn)) + cn/3^lgn

T(n) = n * T(0) + c

T(n) = 3n + c
```

The answer's `O(n)` though..What is wrong with my steps?

Comment: You should apply the Master Theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
T(n) = 3T(n/3) + n/3
T(n/3) = 3T(n/9) + n/9

T(n) = 3(3T(n/9) + n/9) + n/3
     = 9T(n/9) + 2*n/3      //statement 1

T(n/9)= 3T(n/27) + n/27
T(n)  = 9 (3T(n/27)+n/27) + 2*n/3 // replacing T(n/9) in statement 1
      =  27 T (n/27) + 3*(n/3)

T(n)  = 3^k* T(n/3^k) + k* (n/3) // eventually
```

replace k with log n to the base 3.

```
T(n)  = n T(1) + (log n) (n/3);
// T(1) = 3
T(n)  = 3*n + (log n) (n/3);
Hence , O (n* logn)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Eventually it'll look like.. `T(n) = 3^k (T(n/3^k)) + cn/3^k`

No. Eventually it'll look like

```
T(n) = 3^k * T(n/3^k) + k*n/3
```

You've opened the parenthesis inaccurately.

Answer (score 0):

These types of problems are easily solved using the [masters theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). In your case `a = b = 3`, `c = log3(3) = 1` and because `n^c` grows with the same rate as your `f(n) = n/3`, you fall in the second case.

Here you have your `k=1` and therefore the answer is `O(n log(n))`

Answer (score 0):

This question can be solved by Master Theorem:
In a recursion form :
[image]

where a>=1, b>1, k >=0 and p is a real number, then:

1. if a > b<sup>k</sup>, then
   [image: first case of master theorem]
2. if a = b<sup>k</sup>

   ```
      a.) if p >-1, then
   ```

[image: 2.a case of master theorem]

```
       b.) if p = -1, then
```

[image]

```
       c.) if p < -1, then
```

[image]
3. if a < b<sup>k</sup>
a.) if p >=0, then

[image]
b.) if p<0, then T(n) = O(n<sup>k</sup>)

So, the above equation

```
   T(n) = 3T(n/3) + n/3  

a = 3, b = 3, k =1, p =0
```

so it fall into 2.a case, where a = b<sup>k</sup>
So answer will be

```
O(n⋅log(n))
```